# No me imprime los datos y se termina el programa

Tags: c

El Programa no ejecuta lo que se solicita en la opción 2 que es **Impresión de datos**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define tam 100
#define iva 0.12
void ProductosAgotados(int,char[][tam],int[],float[]);
void Datos(int,char[][tam],int[],float[]);
float ValorTotal(int[],int[],float[]);
void main()
{
    int op, cantProdAgotados,cant[tam],cantProd[tam];
    float precio[tam];
    char nombreProducto[tam][tam];
    while(op!=3)
    {
        printf("\n1.Productos Agotados(Ingreso de datos)\n2.Impresion de Datos\n3.Salir\n");
        printf("Escoja la opción:");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:
                   printf("Usted ha ingresado a la opción 1\n");
                   ProductosAgotados(cantProdAgotados,nombreProducto,cant,precio);
                   getchar();
                   getchar();
                   system("clear");
                   
            break;
            case 2:
                  Datos(cantProdAgotados,nombreProducto,cant,precio);
                  getchar();
                  getchar();
                  system("clear");
            break;
            case 3:
                  
                   printf("Fin del programa\n");
            break;
            default:
                    printf("Opción inválida.Intente nuevamente\n");
            break;
        }
    }    
}

void ProductosAgotados(int cantProdAgotados,char nombreProducto[][tam],int cant[],float precio[])
{
    int cont0=0,cont=1,cont1=1,cantProd;
    float subtotal,total,valorUnitario,iva1;
     do
        {
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad de listas a crear:");
            scanf("%d",&cantProdAgotados);
            }while(cantProdAgotados<=0);
                    
                 while(cont<=cantProdAgotados)
                    {
                        printf("Lista #%d\n",cont0+1);
                        do
                        {
                        printf("Ingrese la cantidad de productos:");
                        scanf("%d",&cant[cont0]);
                        }while(cant<=0);
                        cont1=1;
                        while(cont1<=cant[cont0])
                        {
                            getchar();
                            printf("Ingrese el nombre del producto:");
                            fgets(nombreProducto[cont0],tam,stdin);
                            printf("Ingrese la cantidad:");
                            scanf("%d",&cantProd);
                            printf("Ingrese el precio:");
                            scanf("%f",&precio[cont0]);
                        cont1++;
                        }
                    cont++;
                    }
}

void Datos(int cantProdAgotados,char nombreProducto[][tam],int cant[],float precio[])
{
     int cont0;
    for(cont0=0;cont0<cantProdAgotados;cont0++)
    {
        printf("Datos de la lista N°%d\n",cont0+1);
        printf("Cantidad de productos:%d\n",cant[cont0]);
        printf("Nombre del producto%s\n",nombreProducto[cont0]);
        printf("Precio:%.1f\n",precio[cont0]);
    }
    printf("El total es:%.2f\n", ValorTotal(cantProdAgotados,cant,precio));
}

float ValorTotal(int cantProdAgotados[],int cant[],float precio[])
{
    int cont0,cont1=0,cantProd;
    float valorUnitario=0,subtotal=0,iva1=0,total=0;
    for(cont0=0;cont0<cantProdAgotados[cont1];cont0++)
    {
        valorUnitario=(cantProd)*(precio[cont0]);
        subtotal=subtotal+valorUnitario;
        iva1=subtotal*iva;
        total=subtotal+iva1;
        
    }
    return total;

}
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la variable  cantProdAgotados la pasas a la función ProductosAgotados como  valor,  por lo tanto, esta función  no actualizará la variable al  retornar y cuando entra a Datos la variable sigue  en su valor inicial. Prueba pasando la variable cantProdAgotados por referencia, esto es: 
void ProductosAgotados(int & cantProdAgotados,char nombreProducto[][tam],int cant[],float precio[]). La tienes que modificar tambien en la declaración  de arriba.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich en [tag:c] no existe el paso por referencia.

Comment: Tienes razón, no me percaté  en eso, entonces, no te queda otra que como puntero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cuando a una función le pasas una variable *por valor*, lo que sucede es que la función recibe una copia de la variable original:

```
void ProductosAgotados(int cantProdAgotados,char nombreProducto[][tam],int cant[],float precio[])
//                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
//                          por valor
```

El efecto de esta copia es que todos los cambios que se hagan en la variable dentro de la función no van a tener efecto en la variable original

```
void ProductosAgotados(int cantProdAgotados,char nombreProducto[][tam],int cant[],float precio[])
{
    int cont0=0,cont=1,cont1=1,cantProd;
    float subtotal,total,valorUnitario,iva1;
     do
        {
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad de listas a crear:");
            scanf("%d",&cantProdAgotados); // <<--- cambio local
            }while(cantProdAgotados<=0);
```

Y este es básicamente tu problema.

Cuando necesites modificar variables dentro de una función tienes que usar punteros:

```
void ProductosAgotados(int * cantProdAgotados,char nombreProducto[][tam],int cant[],float precio[])
{
    int cont0=0,cont=1,cont1=1,cantProd;
    float subtotal,total,valorUnitario,iva1;
     do
        {
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad de listas a crear:");
            scanf("%d",cantProdAgotados); // <<---
            }while(*cantProdAgotados<=0); // <<---
 

}

// ...

case 1:
    printf("Usted ha ingresado a la opción 1\n");
    ProductosAgotados(&cantProdAgotados,nombreProducto,cant,precio);
    //                ^
```

Luego tienes otro error que aún no ha aflorado, pero ahí esá:

```
void Datos(int cantProdAgotados,char nombreProducto[][tam],int cant[],float precio[])
//         ^^^ int
{
     int cont0;
    for(cont0=0;cont0<cantProdAgotados;cont0++)
    {
        printf("Datos de la lista N°%d\n",cont0+1);
        printf("Cantidad de productos:%d\n",cant[cont0]);
        printf("Nombre del producto%s\n",nombreProducto[cont0]);
        printf("Precio:%.1f\n",precio[cont0]);
    }
    printf("El total es:%.2f\n", ValorTotal(cantProdAgotados,cant,precio));
    //                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //                                           int
}

float ValorTotal(int cantProdAgotados[],int cant[],float precio[])
//               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                    int [] ¿¿??
{
    int cont0,cont1=0,cantProd;
    float valorUnitario=0,subtotal=0,iva1=0,total=0;
    for(cont0=0;cont0<cantProdAgotados[cont1];cont0++)
    {
        valorUnitario=(cantProd)*(precio[cont0]);
        subtotal=subtotal+valorUnitario;
        iva1=subtotal*iva;
        total=subtotal+iva1;
        
    }
    return total;

}
```

Una variable o es entera o es un array de enteros, no puede ser las dos cosas a la vez.

Entiendo que el código debería quedar así:

```
float ValorTotal(int cantProdAgotados,int cant[],float precio[])
{
    int cantProd;
    float valorUnitario=0,subtotal=0,iva1=0,total=0;
    for(int cont0=0;cont0<cantProdAgotados;cont0++)
    {
        valorUnitario=(cantProd)*(precio[cont0]);
        subtotal=subtotal+valorUnitario;
        iva1=subtotal*iva;
        total=subtotal+iva1;
        
    }
    return total;

}
```

Peeeeero te seguirá fallando, porque ... ¿qué valor tiene `cantProd`? Es una variable que declaras pero a la que nunca jamás le asignas un valor, así que todos los cálculos que utilicen esa variable van a estar necesariamente mal